# Issue with angular.copy

Tags: angularjs

i am using angular.copy to do deep copy, and after that i want to updated certain key but it is removing other key,values from the copied object.

```
var test={name:'ankit',title:'dwivedi',id:null};
var test1={};
angular.copy(test,test1);
test1.id="547";
```

Now test1 is only containing id, test{id:'547'} and name and title are removed but I want them also

Comment: It works for me as expected http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2462/

Comment: try test = angular.copy(test1) http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2464/

Comment: @DmitriyNevzorov  : there was issue from my side both of solutions are working